# Android drawable Shape corner

Tags: android, android-drawable, shapes

I have a question about the radius value inside the corners tag,
what is this radius means actually? is there a center or what? 
sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<corners
    android:radius="20dp" />

<solid
    android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

<stroke
    android:color="#FFFFFF"
    android:width="2dp" />

<size
    android:width="165dp"
    android:height="40dp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

> A picture is worth a thousand words
>   [image]

I will demo for you. Here is the original rectangle

[image]

In your xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="45dp" />

    <solid android:color="#22B14C" />
</shape>
```

The result

[image]

4 corners will be rounded by default, if you want round at a specific corner, you can use 4 of these tags:

- android:bottomLeftRadius
- android:bottomRightRadius
- android:topLeftRadius
- android:topRightRadius

Another example using `android:bottomLeftRadius`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="45dp"/>

    <solid android:color="#22B14C" />
</shape>
```

The result

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!!! This is exactly what I am looking for lol. Really thank you so much dude.